# Are distributed file systems and naming services middleware?

Tags: distributed-system, middleware

From *Distributed Systems* by Coulours, a distributed system is partitioned into layers

[image]

Middleware is defined as

> **Middleware** was defined in Section 1.5.1 as a layer of software whose
>   purpose is  to  mask  heterogeneity  and  to  provide  a  convenient 
>   programming  model  to  application programmers. Middleware is
>   represented by processes or objects in a  set of computers that
>   interact with each other to implement communication and 
>   resource-sharing  support  for  distributed  applications.  It  is 
>   concerned  with  providing useful building blocks for the construction
>   of software components that  can work with one another in a
>   distributed system. In particular, it raises the level  of the
>   communication activities of application programs through the support
>   of  abstractions such as remote method invocation; communication
>   between a group  of processes; notification of events; the
>   partitioning, placement and retrieval of  shared data objects amongst
>   cooperating computers; the replication of shared data  objects; and
>   the transmission of multimedia data in real time.

Distributed file systems are defined as

> **A distributed file system** enables programs to store and access remote files exactly as they 
>   do  local  ones,  allowing  users  to  access  files  from  any  computer  on  a  network.  The 
>   performance and reliability experienced for access to files stored at a server should be 
>   comparable to that for files stored on local disks. 
>   In this chapter we define a simple architecture for file systems and describe two basic distributed file service implementations with contrasting designs that have been in widespread use for over two decades: the Sun Network File System, NFS, and the Andrew File System, AFS.

Naming services are defined as

> This  chapter  introduces  **the  name  service**  as  a  distinct  service  that  is  used  by  client 
>   processes to obtain attributes such as the addresses of resources or objects when given 
>   their names. The entities named can be of many types, and they may be managed by 
>   different services. For example, name services are often used to hold the addresses and 
>   other details of users, computers, network domains, services and remote objects. As well 
>   as name services, we describe directory services, which look up services when given 
>   some of their attributes. Examples are DNS, GNS, and LDAP

Which layer(s) in a distributed system do distributed file systems and naming services belong to?

Are distributed file systems and naming services  middleware?
Are distributed file systems and naming services  not considered as middleware according to  the following two from the book?

Distributed file systems (Ch12) and naming services (Ch 13) are missing in categories of middleware:

[image]

Distributed file systems (Ch12) and naming services (Ch 13) are specified outside middleware:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: "Masking Heterogeneity" is a good way to describe middleware.  Ask yourself which components do this.

Comment: Can I ask you if distributed file systems and naming services mask heterogeneity so as to belong to middleware or to application and service layer or OS layer?

Comment: In the sense that they can be used in a homogeneous way, yes.  I consider middleware more like the software that connects together disparate, otherwise incompatible systems.

Comment: Do database systems belong to middleware?

Comment: Do database systems connect two heterogenous systems together?

Comment: Do they? Do database systems and their client side libraries and programs reside on two different systems?

Comment: Not necessarily in a heterogenous manner.

Comment: JDBC, ODBC are both capable of working across heterogenous systems

Comment: Well, yes, but the primary feature of database systems is to provide data, not to connect disparate systems together.

Comment: Does the primary feature of database systems include providing data to systems across networks, regardless of whether they are heterogeneous or not?

Comment: If that is part of their feature set, yes.

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article on Middleware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middleware#Other_examples): *"Middleware can be described as the dash ("-") in client-server, or the -to- in peer-to-peer."*

Comment: Maybe I am wrong. But here is my understanding. In the quote I gave, middleware is a layer in a vertical organization of a distributed system, for abstracting heterogenity of lower layer and providing unifom interface to upper layer. Client and server, and peer and peer are really another story: they are different processes running in the same layer, for instance, the application layer.

Comment: My point is that middleware is neither client or server, neither peer nor other peer.  That's why it's called middleware.

Comment: Thanks for the wikipedia link. I realize there is another   meaning of middleware unrelated to my post: brokers.

Comment: "Broker" is a good word.  While there isn't a *precise* definition, the generally-accepted definition of middleware is "Software that glues together disparate systems, systems that otherwise wouldn't be able to talk to each other."  The systems being glued together might have different data schemas, different communication mechanisms, different business rules, or all of the above.

Comment: In my post, middleware is a layer in a vertical organization of a distributed system, sitting between the upper layer and the lower layer, for masking heterogenity of lower layer and providing unifom interface to upper layer. In the wikipedia link, middleware is a borker connecting two processes in the same layer, for inter process communication. They are two unrelated meanings.

Comment: Nevertheless, they both illustrate the same concept: providing a translation layer between two pieces of software.

Answer (score 2):

There is no authoritative definition of middleware.  The term emerged to coin the additional software components that you need to get the application communicate with other components that may be distributed on the network.  It is difficult to define it properly, since it addresses a large spectrum of needs.

For example, for your data, you'll probably rely on some vendor specific middleware that is not included in the OS, which is on the client side and on the server side to organize the communications. The communication component is a middleware. The database server itself is not: it's at the other end (endware?)

In this perspective, the definition of Coulours might be ambiguous or too broad, since it could give the impression that the whole DBMS could be middleware ( it shares data resources with applications and hide the details).  But it is not, and Coulours has a separate chapter about sharing data.

The same applies to distributed file systems and name services.  Although they would fall under Coulour's middleware definition, these services are in reality deeply intertwined with the operating system and difficult to put in a layer above the OS. This is why Coulours put them in a separate chapter on system services and does not categorize them as middleware.

Comment: Thanks. Why are distributed file systems and naming services not above middleware, but below middleware, if not middleware

Comment: @Tim because they are closer to the OS. Example of active directory: it’s used at OS level to grand access to files. Take DNS: as soon as you’re using TCP/IP you’ll use web addresses and Tcp/Ip stack delivered with the os will resolve the names.  So for application programmer, this is transparently hidden by OS functions.

Comment: Do database systems belong to middleware?  Applications usually don't contain databases, but have data access sublayers to access database systems. So I guess database systems don't belong to application layer, so they belong to middleware layer

Comment: @Tim Is there any database mentioned in your list of middleware? I don’t think so: database is not a middleware, but an end-ware. Database drivers may belong ho the middleware. Because middleware is about communication between components.